# Diffrence PYGIT2 verses PYGIT?

Tags: gitpython, pygit2

So I see there is a "pip install gitpython" and "pygit2" - but cannot seem to determine wha is the difference between the two.

pros/cons - (A) does this, (B) does that - instead

All I am trying to do is automate some GIT to SVN tasks that various existing git-svn tools do not support.  I do this by hand now manually - and want to automate it.

My hunch is: pygit2 - is if I want really low level stuff - and gitpython is more high level but can't really tell.